# Java auto mouse

Tags: java, mouse, click

I am making a program which plays minesweeper automaticaly. I am using the mouse press function to click the squares. Is there a way of giving focus to the minesweeper program without clicking on the tab at the bottom of the monitor??? Thanks

Comment: Would that be a Swing Application? Or an Applet?

Comment: its just running off the console at the moment but in the future it might be swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of giving focus to the minesweeper program without clicking on the tab at the bottom of the monitor?

You mean the Windows task bar?

An application automatically gets focus when it is started. If the user clicks on another applcation then the user must also request focus to go back to the application by clicking on the task bar or by using Alt-Tab.

If your program doesn't have focus then you can't just grab focus, because the user is in control of the desktop and not your program.

Answer (score 3):

You  can simulate mouse click using [`Robot`](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) (not rajni :P).

- [Here is example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/simulating-mouse-and-key-presses.html)

Comment: is there a way to give focus to the game with out using the click function

Comment: @Ste T What is your exact requirement , So that we can have alternatives

Comment: @Ste T You can set your game bound's and set mouse at that position then simulate click and get focus